# How can I access a JavaScript array in JSP

Tags: javascript, jsp, jstl

I want to access AJAX value in JSP. I am able to get the values by using ajax from backend that I need to use in the JSP page.

What I want to achieve is described below:

1. When a user clicks on any category AJAX call will be made to defaulty, after what I want to load received subcategories in the `<div>` of the category;
2. I tried to use AJAX to get values and then in JavaScript i am able to get the values in an array. I tried to store that array in a JSTL tag like `<c:set var="subCatIds">subCategoryIds</c:set>` but I didn't succeed.

Answer (score 0):

The turn of events, as you understand it, is wrong. What I can get from your post is the following:

1. Initially load the view by a servlet. It doesn't have any subcategories. but all first-level directories are populated;
2. You want to populate subdirectories on some event, i.e. button click, hover, etc. For that you're sending an ajax request, specifying parent dir as request parameter, for example by `$.get()`, intercept that request in a servlet, and get the response with subdirectories from that servlet in, for example JSON;
3. In a callback function you are having a JSON with the data you want. Iterating over it, you'll create the HTML structure you want, and finally you'll set the inner HTML of the initial called div with that content.

If my understanding is correct, just go ahead, do that step by step, and you'll get the desired result.

Comment: You must also add that JSTL and/or EL doesn't work to handle ajax responses.